# Why doesn't 'IsMouseDirectlyOverChanged' fire when moving the mouse over a Window or Control?

Tags: c#, wpf

Kinda scratching my head on this. I'm trying to detect when the user's mouse is over the client area of a `Window` so I can run some specific code (i.e. I'm not just doing something in a style trigger.)

Here's my code...

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="Playground.MainWindow"
    xmlns   = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Width="800" Height="450" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    Title="Test Window">

    <Button x:Name="TestButton" Content="I Don't Do Anything"
        Padding="16"
        FontSize="24"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />

</Window>
```

Code-behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow {

    public MainWindow(){

        InitializeComponent();

        IsMouseDirectlyOverChanged += MainWindow_IsMouseDirectlyOverChanged;
    }

    private void MainWindow_IsMouseDirectlyOverChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
        Console.WriteLine(nameof(MainWindow_IsMouseDirectlyOverChanged));
    }
}
```

...but the event never fires.

To see if it was something specific to the window, I instead attached the event to the button, like so...

```
TestButton.IsMouseDirectlyOverChanged += MainWindow_IsMouseDirectlyOverChanged;
```

It now fires, but only when I physically click on the button, not when I hover over it.

So how can I detect when I'm hovering directly over the client area?

Answer (score 1):

[UIElement.IsMouseDirectlyOver property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.ismousedirectlyover?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_UIElement_IsMouseDirectlyOver) from MSDN.

> **Remarks:** Unlike IsMouseOver, this property is only true if the mouse pointer is over the literal element—as it is for a hit test. If the mouse pointer is instead over a child element, in particular over elements that are part of an element's deeper template and compositing, this property will be false.

I think this explains why it does not fire on the window, I can't explain why it does fired when you click the button (not when hovering over it).

How about `MouseEnter`/`MouseLeave` events and `IsMouseOver` property?

Comment: No, that doesn't quite explain it because a window *is* an element.  Plus, the button didn't work.  Of note, the `WM_NCHITTEST` messages are firing the way one would expect them to be, so I know the mouse is being registered as being over the client area.  The issue with using that is to the Win32 subsystem, there are no children because WPF is rendered on the main window (unlike GDI+ apps where each child is its own window), hence not being able to use `WM_NCHITTEST` with `HTCLIENT` for a WPF app.

Comment: And I tried with the `MouseEnter`/`MouseLeave` but they didn't work either.  Could I ask you to try my code above?  I'm using a virtual machine and I know from past experience, sometimes that's the cause of mouse issues. But not having a straight Windows machine, I can't tell for sure.

Comment: I tried you code and it behaves exactly the way you described.

Comment: Ok... duuuuh! The answer makes so much sense now that I figured it out.  Check out what I just posted.  It was so simple I'm almost embarrassed I didn't think of that sooner. :)

Comment: I just had another thought (that I haven't yet had a chance to check.) I think the reason it fires on the button when you click the event is because when you click it, it changes the template, and in the split moment that the template is being swapped out, the mouse is probably directly over the button's root in the visual tree (i.e. the button!) so it fires.  This is just a guess, but it does make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured it out. It doesn't work quite as one would expect because the mouse is responding to the Visual tree, not the Logical tree.

### Initial Attempt

I came to discover this by first hooking up a `MouseMove` event (which works on the logical tree) for the `Window`, and in the handler, I added the following:

```
Console.WriteLine($"The mouse is over '{System.Windows.Input.Mouse.DirectlyOver}'");
```

In the console, I saw it was actually over a `Border` control, not the `Window` as I was expecting. That makes sense as the `Border` is part of the default template for the `Window`.

I next cracked open Snoop and took a look at the visual tree and sure enough, between the `Window` and the `Button` was that `Border` (amongst a few other things.)  Ok, simple... I'll walk the visual tree from the `Button` to the `Border`.

BUT... during the `Window`'s constructor, the `Button` doesn't yet have a visual parent because the `Window`'s template isn't yet loaded! (For some reason, you can't get to it in the `OnApplyTemplate` override either, even after calling `base.OnApplyTemplate` but I digress.)

So, knowing it would definitely be there during the `Loaded` event, I hooked it up like so...

```
Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
```

And in the handler, I did this...

```
private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {

    Loaded -= MainWindow_Loaded;

    var parent = (DependencyObject)TestButton;

    while(parent != null && !(parent is Border))
        parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parent);

    (parent as Border).IsMouseDirectlyOverChanged += MainWindow_IsMouseDirectlyOverChanged;
}
```

And once I did that, I got the behavior I expected. I was finally getting the events.

### Clarity and Simplicity

However, I wasn't a fan of this *at all* because it not only looks clumsy and verbose, but it also relies on the template for the `Window` never changing. Not good!

Then I had a head-slap moment.  The answer was so stupidly simple I was almost embarrassed:

```
<Window x:Class="SystemDialogPlayground.MainWindow"
    xmlns   = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Width="800" Height="450" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    Title="Test Window">

    <!-- Add your own border you can track against -->
    <Border x:Name="ClientArea" Background="Transparent">

        <Button x:Name="TestButton" Content="I Don't Do Anything"
            Padding="16"
            FontSize="24"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />

    </Border>

</Window>
```

Yes, it's as simple as adding my own border, which I then connect up like so...

```
ClientArea.IsMouseDirectlyOverChanged += ClientArea_IsMouseDirectlyOverChanged;
```

And that worked exactly the same as the 'clumsy' way, but much simpler and cleaner... no walking the tree, and not fragile based on the template.

Sometimes us programmers amaze ourselves at how many lefts we'll take to go right. Tonight I was doing donuts!

### Important: Set a background!

*Make sure to give your border a background, even if only set to `Transparent` like I have here. This is because if the background is null, it doesn't exist, therefore there's nothing for the mouse to be 'over' so you won't get any mouse events. Setting it to `Transparent` addresses that simply and without altering the visuals at all.*

Hope this helps!